# How to find the Min of a list grouping the values

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
[[1,John,4], [1,Peter,6],[2,Maddison,2],[2,Nicollette,3]]
```

So for every item in the list that has the index `l[0]` similar, I should calculate the minimum of the `l[3]`.

**Expected**

```
MinimumLists [[1,John,4],[2,Maddison,2]]
```

Comment: What? This is not well specified at all.

Comment: It's not clear what is the input here. Can you put it in a python format? Also, what is max or min based on? You have 3 numbers and a strong per row.

Comment: you are right guys, now i updated my question

Answer (score 0):

The lists can be computed using the following code:

```
  grp_lists = list(set([[y for y in input_list if(y[0]==x[0])] for x in input_list])) # to remove duplicate lists
  min_lists = [ min(x, key=lambda t: t[2]) for x in grp_lists ]
```